# How to call a function with a condition that needs to call to other function

Tags: python, function-composition

I have 3 functions that call each other and I have problems to make the call.

- `function1`: Generate a dictionary as follows with fixed values:

```
{'A':100, 'B':200, 'C':300}
```

- `function2`: Randomly generates a letter from the keys of the dictionary
- `function3`: Randomly generates a number in the range 0 to X, where X is the number matching the key selected by `function2`.

How can I combine these three functions?

Comment: What language is the function in?

Comment: From your posting history I guessed that your problem is in Python. Please fix the tag if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, this is one of them:

```
import random

def f1():
    return {'A':100, 'B':200, 'C':300}

def f2(d):
    return random.choice(list(d.keys())), d

def f3(k, d): 
    return random.randint(0, d[k])

print(f3(*f2(f1())))
```

`f2()` returns a tuple with the random key and the dict which are getting passed as individual arguments to `f3()`.

Since the dict is meant to be static anyways, you could also just use `f1()` again:

```
import random

def f1():
    return {'A':100, 'B':200, 'C':300}

def f2(d):
    return random.choice(list(d.keys()))

def f3(k, d):
    return random.randint(0, d[k])

print(f3(f2(f1()),f1()))
```

Comment: I've tried with both but I have the following message: dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @CristinaDominguezFernandez Sorry, my bad. I must be `list(d.keys())`. Changed it

Comment: Or `random.choice`?